# How do I make a game with multiple levels?

Tags: game-engine

I want to make a full fan made Mario 3D world style 2 player game. How do I make a game with multiple levels in blender? Is there something like a sequence editor for video game levels or files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blend file can contain [multiple scenes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/scenes/introduction.html), each game level is created in its own scene. The [scene actuator](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/game_engine/logic/actuators/types/scene.html) then changes the current scene in a game.

Answer (score 1):

Set a property on the player. Select the end of level object. Open the Logic Editor. Add a Collision Sensor and add the players property into the Property field. Add a Scene Actuator, change the mode to Set Scene, and type in the desired scene. Connect the Sensor and Actuator (an And Controller will appear between them automatically).

Comment: Thank you very much.